# Local mosquitto not visible from docker

Tags: docker, security, mosquitto

I have a local mosquitto broker running on ubuntu with `bind_address localhost`. If I try to access this broker from a docker container with node-red on the same host, it is **not** reachable. If I don't bind mosquitto to localhost, all works well.

What can I do to make mosquitto visible only on local machine but also accessible for local docker containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost` in the docker container is not the same `localhost` as the machine running the Docker engine.

If you want to access the broker you will need to use the address of the host machine on the Docker virtual network  (e.g. 172.17.0.1 bound to device docker0 is the default I think).

You can keep the `bind_address` entry, but you will need to add a second `listener` entry for the address bound to the docker0 interface.